# Auto Populating lookup field

Tags: process-builder, opportunity, lookup, contact, automation

I have a lookup field to the Contacts object on Opportunities object which is to define the Primary Point of Contact (dont want to use Contact Roles). There is another lookup field on that Contact record page which is supposed to be a lookup back to the Opportunity.

When a Lead gets converted to an Opportunity, I want my sales rep to use the lookup field (Primary Point of Contact) to select the contact. From there, I would like to have the Opportunity lookup field on the Contact Record page to be populated.

How can I configure this?

Comment: Are your Contacts only ever going to be associated with one Opportunity?

Comment: Not necessarily, there are other opportunity record types; for a renewal, upsell, etc.

Comment: Then how do you want to populate a single lookup field on the Contact? That's really what related lists are for.

Comment: I only started down this path because I want to have my sales team send out emails from a list view on their opportunities. I know salesforce has the mass email feature but its only on leads and contacts, so i am trying to populate opportunity info on the contact list view. Any opportunities closed in the past 30 days will get sent an email.